# Using POST instead of GET for long queries in Sunspot / Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, rsolr

I need to run a long query over Solr but Sunspot is using GET as the default method. I know that this is something supported on RSolr, but i don't know if i can do it through Susnpot.

Thanks!

Comment: Sunspot has nothing to do with the http verb.  Show us the form you are using to submit the search request.

Comment: @JTG The verb is not in regards to the form => rails, but between the app and the Solr backend, where Solr supports both GET and POST as methods to submit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to the Sunspot source on GitHub](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/ec64df6a526d738f9f77c039679b344f908d3298/sunspot/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb#L48), Sunspot already uses POST as the default for submitting queries to Solr when searching. This was changed in 2011, so if you have a VERY old version of Sunspot, that might be an issue.

Otherwise if you're still seeing GETs on the server side, it'd be helpful to see the code you're actually using for searching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized that my problem was other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901299/too-many-boolean-clauses-exception-in-solr