# Search Solr for a large number of specific documens

Tags: solr

I have read http://solr.pl/en/2011/12/19/do-i-have-to-look-for-maxbooleanclauses-when-using-filters/ and [Too many boolean clauses exception in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901299/too-many-boolean-clauses-exception-in-solr).

My Solr has about 2 million documents.  I can retrieve specific documents by set query or filter query to the IDs of the specific documents.  By doing this, I can find the facets and clusters among these specific documents.  The query I set is:

id:1234567 or id:1234567 or id:2345678 ...

However, when I have, say 200 specific documents, Solr complains that my query has too many boolean clauses.  Should I simply increase the maxBooleanClauses or there should be another approach for this kind of query?

Comment: How dynamic is the list of ids? can it be pregenerated (meaning, can a document be tagged with "belongs to xyz") when the documents are inserted? How often do the group ownership change (meaning, can you reindex the documents necessary when the ownership changes)?

Comment: The list of ids is very dynamic.  In this second, I may be interested in these 1000 documents.  In the next second, I may be interested in another 1000 documents.  I appreciate your approach by using tag.  But there could be a few concurrent searches going on to make the tag approach difficult.

Comment: Is the index distributed, or does it live on one server? You could try creating a temporary collection, index the ids as separate documents to that collection and then join against the original collection to retrieve the documents.

Comment: The index is distributed to 4 cores.  The collection idea is interesting.  Wonder how quick can a core be created and processed.  I want everthing to be completed within 3 seconds.

Comment: Distributed indices aren't joinable (as both cores have to live on the same server), so the easiest solution is probably to increase the number of boolean clauses. :-|

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of too many boolean clauses exception in solr.
You are having document ids, I had the acl ids(access control list)

Steps I have taken to overcome the issue is

1. Increase the maxBooleanCLauses
2. Used the in the filter query as &fq=acl:(id1 or id2...)
3. If the count of acl is greater than 8000 then i am sending multiple request with the below logic

   StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder(5000);
   if (acls.length > 8000) {
       Integer aclCounter = 0;
       long requestCnt = Math.round(Math.ceil((acls.length / 8000.0)));
       for (int i = 0; i < requestCnt; i++) {
           queryString = new StringBuilder(acls.length * 10);
           queryString.append("&fq=acl:(");
           for (int j = 0; j < 8000 && aclCounter < acls.length; aclCounter++, j++) {
           queryString.append(acls[aclCounter]).append(APPEND_OR);
           }
            queryString.replace(queryString.length() - 4, queryString.length(), ")");
         // build the solr request and sent it to get the response
       }
   }