# 400 Bad request: solr too many boolean clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I keep getting *too many OR clauses error* in Rails with Solr. I have even increased the **maxBooleanClauses** limit to **10240** by logging into the **Solr Admin UI**, just to see if it fixed the issue. But it did not.

How can I fix this issue. Whenever a user performs a search there are too many or clauses?

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16901299/3863146) but it did not work. Is there any other place where I should update the count.

Comment: modify the maxBooleanClauses variable in solrconfig.xml file and get rid of the exception

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `maxBooleanClauses` variable in `solrconfig.xml` file.

This will help you to get rid of the exception.

You can adjust that parameter in  `solrconfig.xml`

```
<maxBooleanClauses>3024</maxBooleanClauses>
```

Modify the number.

Comment: Thanks @abhijit, I tried doing that inside one folder called, `solr/sitename/solrconfig.xml`, I even did it in the cores which I have created for my website(`solr/my_core/conf/solrconfig.xml`) but it didn't work. I still keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this exception you can set **maxBooleanClauses** config in Solr solrconfig.xml

Moreover, still a jira ticket is open for permanent fix

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4586

But please remember that changing this limit can have a negative effect on performance and memory usage.
http://solr.pl/en/2011/12/19/do-i-have-to-look-for-maxbooleanclauses-when-using-filters/

Comment: Yes I restarted the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if the value on `<maxBooleanClauses>` inside the `<query>` tag is higher than the maxBooleanClauses from the global context, it will get ignored.

You can try to override or create a variable on the global context like this:

```
<solr>
    <int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:10240}</int>
...
```

Here are some useful links:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/format-of-solr-xml.html#global-maxbooleanclauses
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/query-settings-in-solrconfig.html